# How to set cell format to show 1 decimal in percent formatting with Excel::Writer::XLSX in more than one locale?

Tags: excel, perl, xlsx

I'm generating XLSX documents with Perl and Excel::Writer::XLSX.
The generated documents will be opened in multiple countries with multiple different locales.
I would like to format a cell so a percentage number shown inside has one digit after the decimal point.

When I use `num_format=>9` it shows zero digits, when I use `num_format=>10` it shows 2 digits. When I use a format string like `0.0%` it works fine in one locale, but does not work in another, as the other locale uses `","` instead of `"."` as decimal separator.

How can I format cells showing numbers in a locale-independent way?

Comment: Can't you just use `0.0%` or `0,0%` depending on the locale?

Comment: As it turned out I can't. Even when I generate the XLSX for a given language I still don't know the locale settings of the Excel instances it will be opened on. 
For example I generate XLSX for Vietnamese and use the decimal separator for that locale, but some users in Vietnam will have English Excels and my formatting will not work on their machines.

I could not find any way to set the language or the locale on the generated XLSX.